# Map client application's DTO to service-proxy's DataContract

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, wcf

My idea is to not not expose/use service's Proxy everywhere throughout the application, rather exercising all service communications(using client Proxy) from a single class. To achieve this I have created below class: -

```
namespace MyOrganization.EventSender
{
    using MyOrganization.EventSender.DTOs;
    using MyOrganization.EventSender.Proxy;
    using MyOrganization.EventSender.Utilities;
    using log4net;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceProcess;

    /// <summary>
    /// The User Session Detail Sender
    /// </summary>
    public class SessionDataSender : ISessionDataSender
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        private SessionDataDTO _sessionDataDTO;

        public SessionDataSender(SessionDataDTO sessionDataDTO)
        {
            _sessionDataDTO = sessionDataDTO;
        }


        public bool Send()
        {
            try
            {
                Proxy.MessageProcessorProxy.SessionDetails sd = new Proxy.MessageProcessorProxy.SessionDetails();
                sd.ChangeTime = _sessionDataDTO.ChangeTime;
                sd.ChangeType = _sessionDataDTO.ChangeType;
                sd.Username = _sessionDataDTO.Username;
                sd.SessionId = _sessionDataDTO.SessionId;               

                log.Info($"Sending SessionEvent [{sd.ChangeType}] to Web-Srver.");

                var client = new Proxy.MessageProcessorProxy.MessageProcessorClient();
                var response = client.LogEventDetails(sd);

                Proxy.ProxyFactory.CloseProxy(client as ICommunicationObject);

                log.Info($"Web-Server Response: [{response.ResponseMessage}]. Reference: [ {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sd)} ] ");

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error($"Exception: [{ex.ToString()}]");

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my questions are: -

- Is it good to map every DTOs into Proxy's DataContract? As my this class will grow with more service calls with different DTOs.
- How this class should be architect so that it doesn't violate SRP/Design-patterns?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it good to map every DTOs into Proxy's DataContract? As my this
>   class will grow with more service calls with different DTOs.

Yes, mapping to your own domain improves modularity by decoupling the DTO library from your domain.

> How this class should be architect so that it doesn't violate
>   SRP/Design-patterns?

1. Use either a custom or existing mapping framework to remove the boiler-plate mapping code from your flow. You could create a `Mapper` class.
2. Consider using [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_software_development) for refactoring boiler-plate try-catch blocks. You could create a `LogEntryExitAndErrorAnnotation` class.
3. Your reponse object is not required
4. Use a `using` block to dispose the client
5. Don't use a `boolean`, when it is always `true` on success, and hidden when an *exception* occured.

adapted:

```
     [LogEntryExitAndErrorAnnotation]
     public void Send()
     {
          var sd = mapper.Map<Proxy.MessageProcessorProxy.SessionDetails>(_sessionDataDTO);               

          // see notes below why to use an adapter
          using (var client = new MessageProcessorClientAdapter(
              new Proxy.MessageProcessorProxy.MessageProcessorClient()))
                  client.LogEventDetails(sd);
     }
```

### Note on (4)

As the OP pointed out: [Dispose could hide the root exception](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources).

To avoid this, you can use an adapter. I would use T4 templates to generate these for all my clients.

Suppose your client interface is

```
public interface IMessageProcessorClient : IDisposable {
    void LogEventDetails(object data); // or typed class
}
```

You can use the code below to have the best possible exception details. If no error occured during the operation, the error of Dispose is thrown, else an aggregate error is thrown.

```
public class MessageProcessorClientAdapter : IMessageProcessorClient {
    public IMessageProcessorClient Source {get; private set;}
    public Exception Error {get;private set;}
    public MessageProcessorClientAdapter(IMessageProcessorClient source) {
        this.Source = source; // check for null
    }
    public void LogEventDetails(object data) {
        try {
            this.Source.LogEventDetails(data);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            this.Error = error;
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        try {
            this.Source.Dispose();
        } catch (Exception error) {
            if (this.Error == null) {
                this.Error = error;
            } else {
                this.Error = new AggregateException(this.Error, error);
            }
        } finally {
            if (this.Error != null) {               
                throw this.Error;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `LogEntryExitAndErrorAnnotation` - oh, this will produce a lot of garbage log entries ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t well, perhaps this is overkill. If the service is hosted in IIS, you could always enable logs here.

Comment: I treat aspect-oriented logging generally as a sign of _I don't know what I'm doing so I'd better log everything_ ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t at my current client, we log this extensively to show other teams we 'did' manage to process their request, so the bug 'must' be at their code ;-)

Comment: So, it is not a good practice to use AOP based logging?

Comment: @Anil Kumar If you decide to log all entry, exit, errors in your service operations, I would suggest to use AOP. The real question is: do you want to log all this information? Like discussed above, if you use IIS, you can enable logs from this API. So, I would say, it depends on what you want, and which technology is available to you.

Comment: point no (4) using block can't be used https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources

Comment: @Anil Kumar Interesting post! However, it is by design that a Dispose exception can hide an exception within the clause. I will update my post with an adapter class to avoid this problem, maintaining the nice Dispose pattern.